# How to set text on AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am having trouble setting a default value on my AutoCompleteTextView.
First, I tried doing `setText("default value")`.
Then, I searched and tried this:

```
autoText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        autoText.showDropDown();
    }
},500);
autoText.setText("chi");
autoText.setSelection(tvNewRestoAddress.getText().length());
```

but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks ok. what is issue?

Comment: the "chi" doesn't show on autocompletetextview. I want to automatically set a "chi" on autocompletetextview when I launch the app.

Comment: Do you have set adapter for autocomplete view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
  AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edt);
    String[] array = {"abc", "bcd", "cde", "def", "efg", "fgh", "PREM"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, array);

    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    autoCompleteTextView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            autoCompleteTextView.setText("PREM");
            autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();

        }
    }, 10);
```

Comment: @ChristianBringino happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Pear"};
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);
     AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
            actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
            actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to add property on XML like -

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    ...

    android:text="Here your text" />
```

or in java

```
autocompletetextview.setText("Here your text");
```